# Getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException when calling Bitmap.SetPixel

Tags: c#, bitmap, console-application

In some kind of way a not so easy bug has sneaked its way into this little piece of code without my knowledge of fixing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    bm.SetPixel(1, 1, Color.AliceBlue);
    bm.Save("C:\\Users\\Lasse\\Pictures\\Midlertidigt\\hej.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);//
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter must be positive and < Width.

Comment: Try `bm.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.AliceBlue);`

Answer (score 5):

You've created an image with a height and width of 1. Coordinates start at 0, therefore the *only* valid first two arguments two `SetPixel` are 0:

```
bm.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.AliceBlue);
```

The only confusing thing is how this could *ever* have worked, as implied by your description.

Comment: Yeah. Funny definition of "out of nowhere" when it is a smple and clear "hey, check your parameters and learn c# basics" case.